# Mirror a folder and extract all zip files in their respective subfolders using powershell

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, batch-file, cmd.exe

I need to maintain a mirror of a unix server folder on a Windows Server for which I am using WinSCP and the following code:

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open sftp://username:password@hostname -hostkey="ssh-rsa 2048 key"
synchronize local "Z:\Mirror" /abbvie-xtract1
exit
```

Now, I need to make a new **Extracted** folder in the Windows Server which has the same structure as **Mirror**, but all the zip files inside  needs to extracted in their respective folders (keeping the structure same, see the image links for clarity) which can be done using as explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42253595/unzip-all-zip-files-in-all-subfolders). But, the problem here is one folder can have multiple zips and if two zips contain same named file and one is different than other then I need to rename one *name-copy*. How can I achieve this?

Structure of Mirror Folder

[image: IMG:]

Structure of New Extracted Folder

[image: IMG:]

Comment: why not just zip on the source and copy to the destination and extract?

Comment: It is zipped in the source. I have to keep two folders, Mirror and Extracted on windows server (Destination). Mirror contains the exact same copy as source but extracted has all the zips extracted.